# Calling IIS AppPool from SQL Server Job (2005)

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, iis-6

I was wondering if it’s possible to make a call to an IIS AppPool from a SQL Server Job (2005).
I am basically looking to have a job monitor a table for an event and if a condition is fired I want to call IIS and shutdown a specific AppPool.

I presume I can do this thru the CLR and .NET from the SQL Server Job but wondered was there an easier way/better way to approach this?

Cheers,
Conor

Comment: The AppPool is hosting a third party Web Service (unable to modify schema) that sits on IIS under our control. This service is called from an array of places in a SOA environment and events of the Request/Response are stored in the SQL Server Table. I then want to have a SQL Server Job to monitor this table by doing an xpath into a specific XML documents and based on a specific response e.g. “Catastrophic Application Error returned”, then call IIS to switch off the AppPool and then raise the alarm bells for investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an [SQLDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) from your Gloal.asax to have SQL Server notify your application when your event occurs.

You can then shutdown the AppPool from your application rather than from SQL Server